# Product of good orbifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, orbifolds

Let $M,N$ be two (very)good orbifold,(i.e. (finitely)covered by a manifold). The local coordinate are given by $U/ \Gamma_M$ and $V/\Gamma_N$

Then the coordinate charts $U\times V/\Gamma_M\times\Gamma_N$ define a orbifold $M\times N$. Can we deduce that $M\times N$ is (very)good?